# Excel formula to search cell values from one column and add values from another cell if true

Tags: worksheet-function

I don't think this should be too complicated for Excel, but I am trying to figure out how to:

1) Determine if a cell in column A contains the text "FF"

2) If so, jump over to the corresponding cell in Column D and add its value

3) Do this all the way down the A column, keeping a running total of all cells in column D if the cell in column A meets the criteria

Basically, I am breaking down a checkbook register by transaction types, such as Groceries, Clothing, Fast Food, Bills, etc.  I want to calculate how much money has gone toward each category.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You can do this almost completely with built-ins, the [`FIND` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/find.php), as well as the `COLUMN` and `ROW` functions.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I did figure out how to do this with the SUMIFS function in Excel. I was merely misunderstanding it earlier. Thank God for the internet! =SUMIFS(D2:D9999, A2:A9999, I10) Breakdown: It adds the cell in column D if the cell in the same row in column A contains the criteria in cell I10. I10 contains the text "FF"; If cell A2 contains "FF", then it adds the value from cell D2. It continues this down the line until A9999. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I know, Excel have special function for this. I dont use MS Excel for now, but look next
http://tipstricksandwe.blogspot.ru/2011/07/conditional-sum-in-ms-excel.html

```
=SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a cumulative conditional sum like this, starting in row 1 and copied down.

```
=SUMIF($A$1:A1,"*ff*",D:D)
```

Sumif() is not case-sensitive. The above will find the text "ff" anywhere in the cell. If you want a whole cell match, use

```
=SUMIF($A$1:A1,"ff",D:D)
```

Other ways to sum up data can be done with Pivot Tables, without any formulas.

Comment: Thank you.  I did change my code to something similar:  =SUMIF($A:$A,I10,$D:$D) -- This allowed me to drag it up and down to other cells beside my legend.  The only thing that changes is the I10, which is handy for this.

Comment: That formula will not give you a running total, though, as you specified in your question. If you want to total by category, a Pivot Table would be much more efficient.